# Is it required to update new passport number in qatar id eventhough final exit from country?

Tags: qatar

I have renewed my passport, I am going to exit from Qatar this month, Is it still required to update my new passport number in qatar id or visa eventhough final exit from Qatar.

My old passport stamped as "PASSPORT CANCELLED, VISA IF ANY REMAINS VALID"